# Positioning a Video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I having been trying for days now to move a video on top of a `<div>` which includes an `<img>`

Effectively I am trying to make the image of a TV show a video on its screen.

Could somebody help me in positioning the video so it is central to the image inside the screen. I can't even get the video to position on top of the `<img>` let alone making it the correct size and centering it.

Thanks in advance. Much appreciated.

```html
<div class="videocontainer">
<h1 class="videosheading"><strong>VIDEOS</strong></h1>
<div class="videogallery">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/TVWALLTWO.jpg">
      <video controls="" height="330" width="440">
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.videosheading {
  color: #E3A750;
  text-align: center;
}
.videogallery {
  height: auto;
}
video {
  background-color: red;
  z-index:-1;
  position:relative
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the video over the responsive image, you need a container that has `position: relative`, than the video must have `position: absolute`. Look at the snippet bellow, hope you get the idea:

```css
.video-cell {
    positon: relative;
}
.video-cell img {
    width: 100%;
}
.video-cell video {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="videocontainer">
    <h1 class="videosheading"><strong>VIDEOS</strong></h1>
    <div class="videogallery">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 video-cell">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/880x660">
                <video controls width="440" height="330">
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
                    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25116/).

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you. Is it possible to make the image stay in the same position and be responsive as well? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: This example **is** with responsive image and **is** with responsive video. You would have to explain better what you need. Also, if you consider this answer good, than mark it for other people who visit this wonderful webiste.